# OpenCV - Lotto number recognition

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I am trying to create a program that will recognize the lottery numbers automaticly.

I have recognized the draw moment, seperated the ball, and now my problem is that i cannot recognize the number on the ball.

This is the original picture:

[image: original]

This is my picture after i find the contours:

[image: contours]

Now for each contour I try to determine if its a number and what number is it. This is where my app fails.

*Important to say that the ball can be in many angles/the lighting can be differnet , which all afect the quality of the pic.

This is an example of a contour img my prog found:

[image]

This is my code for recognizing the number:

```
private void identifyNumber(Mat inFile) {
    System.out.println("\nRunning identifyNumber");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");

    int match_method = Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF;
    Mat img = inFile;
    Mat bestImage = new Mat(), rotImg;
    int bestDegree = 0, bestNumber = 0;
    double lowerstFornumber, lowest = 1E30;
    String templateNumber;

    for (int k=0 ; k<=9; k++) {
        lowerstFornumber = 1E30;
        for(int i=-90; i<=90; i=i+5){
            templateNumber = "C:\\pics\\drawProcessing\\numbers\\" + k + ".png"; 
            Mat templ = Highgui.imread(templateNumber);

            rotImg = rotateImage(img, i);
            int result_cols = rotImg.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
            int result_rows = rotImg.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
            Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

            Imgproc.matchTemplate(rotImg, templ, result, match_method);

            MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

            Point matchLoc;
            if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
                matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
            } else {
                matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
            }

            double minValue = mmr.minVal;

//          System.out.println(i+",maxVal:" +maxValue);

            if(lowerstFornumber > minValue){
                lowerstFornumber = minValue;
            }

            if(lowest > minValue){
                lowest = minValue;
                bestImage = rotImg;
                bestDegree = i;
                bestNumber = arr[k];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("lowerstFornumber " + arr[k] + "  :" + lowerstFornumber);
    }

    System.out.println("bestDegree:" + bestDegree);
    System.out.println("bestNumber:" + bestNumber);
    System.out.println("_lowest:" + lowest);
    Highgui.imwrite("C:\\pics\\drawProcessing\\out-best.jpg", bestImage);    
}
```

Sometimes it finds the number, Sometimes not.
Is it even possible?(I need 100% accuracy)
Am I doning it wrong?

Comment: I would search for more elabote OCR algorithms instead of using matchTemplate. You can search for works that use the MNIST dataset.

Comment: I am trying to use K_nearest as i saw here :http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/. they say i should "teach" the prog with many samples for each digit, but in my case should i just give the prog each number in several angels?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try an affine invariant descriptor for your boxes? You can even start with an easier descriptor, say sift or surf, computed for every region and matched to a database. It should be fast because it looks like scale will not be changing. Sift and surf might give you some results but for something more stable you can use ASIFT.

Answer (score 0):

Not in java, but it describes the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void DetectContour(Mat& img, Mat& res)
{
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Mat edges=img.clone();
    //Canny(img, edges, 50, 190, 3);
    img.copyTo(edges);
    findContours(edges,contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point());
    if(contours.size()>0)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            vector<Point> approx;
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
            double area = contourArea(Mat(approx));

            if(area>200)
                drawContours( res, contours, i, Scalar(255,0,0), CV_FILLED, 8);
        }
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::namedWindow("result");
    Mat img=imread("ball.png");

    // Prepare mask
    Mat mask=Mat::zeros(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
    Mat img_gray;
    cv::cvtColor(img,img_gray,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat res=Mat(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
    res=255;

    vector<Vec3f> circles;

    /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles

    HoughCircles( img_gray, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, img_gray.rows/8, 140, 70, 0,0 );

    /// Draw the circles detected
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // circle outline
        circle( mask, center, radius, Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
    }
    img.copyTo(res,mask);

    cv::cvtColor(res,res,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    threshold(res,res,80,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    mask=0;
    DetectContour(res,mask);

    mask.copyTo(res);

    int element_size=10;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size( 2*element_size + 1, 2*element_size+1 ),Point( element_size, element_size ) );

    int element_size2=5;
    Mat element2 = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size( 2*element_size + 1, 2*element_size+1 ),Point( element_size, element_size ) );

    cv::dilate(res,res,element2);
    cv::erode(res,res,element);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(res,contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point());
    for (int i=0;i<contours.size();++i)
    {
        RotatedRect box = minAreaRect(contours[i]);
        Point2f center, vtx[4];
        box.points(vtx);

        float w=100;
        float h=100;
        // Create a column vector with the coordinates of each point (on the field plane)
        cv::Mat xField;
        xField.create(4, 1, CV_32FC2);
        xField.at<Point2f>(0) = ( vtx[0] );
        xField.at<Point2f>(1) = ( vtx[1] );
        xField.at<Point2f>(2) = ( vtx[2] );
        xField.at<Point2f>(3) = ( vtx[3] );

        // same thing for xImage but with the pixel coordinates instead of the field coordinates, same order as in xField
        cv::Mat xImage;
        xImage.create(4, 1, CV_32FC2);
        xImage.at<Point2f>(0) = ( cv::Point2f(0, 0) );
        xImage.at<Point2f>(1) = ( cv::Point2f(w, 0) );
        xImage.at<Point2f>(2) = ( cv::Point2f(w, h) );
        xImage.at<Point2f>(3) = ( cv::Point2f(0, h) );

        // Compute the homography matrix
        cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(xField,xImage );
        xField.release();
        xImage.release();

        Mat warped;
        warpPerspective(img,warped,H,Size(w,h));
        H.release();
        char win_name[255];
        sprintf(win_name,"number_image %d",i);
        namedWindow(win_name);
        imshow(win_name,warped);
//      cv::waitKey(0);

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        {
            line(img, vtx[j], vtx[(j+1)%4], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, LINE_AA); 
        }

    }




    imshow("result",img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont understandwhat how minAreaRect will help me? the first and second images are my outputs, I identified the contours and limited the 'contourArea' to what i need. the output is the second image, how do i get from the second image, how will minAreaRect help from there to recognize the '4'?

Comment: if after binarization you apply cv::dilate, you'll get contours which includes both digits. After it you can find contours and then min bounding rectangle. It will get you rotated rectangle region which includes the whole number. After it you can unrotate this region (get non dilated digits image) and make digits standing in natural way. Then use standard OCR. If you provide clear image (without red boxes) I'll test my idea and put the code here.

Comment: I've edited my answer. As you can see numbers are bounded by rotated rectangles. You can extract the content of these rectangles and you'll get numbers in natural rotation angle. The algorithm may need some tuning, but I think that the concept is clear.

Comment: Thnks for the help, hmm but this is not realy what i asked. finding the contours is the least of my problems for now. As i wrote i am trying to identfy the numbers(44 as '4', '4'). I tryed using http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/ , but i dont know what my 'teaching images' should be, there could be a milion angels, How would you solve it(just the logic), hundreds of samples?

Comment: I think this article should be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C